# How to exit git difftool when using with Beyond Compare?

Tags: git, beyondcompare, git-difftool

I have configured Beyond Compare as `difftool`.

When I run `$ git difftool`, it opens all the diff files in BC, but sequentially i.e. the first diff file opens, which I have to close so that the next one opens, and so on.

When the file count is too large, I need to keep repeating this for each file. Is there any way to -

1. Quit the diff process midway and return to the `$` prompt? OR
2. Open all the diff files in BC in multiple tabs?
3. Any other good ideas?

Comment: I wonder if you can configure `git difftool` to invoke a wrapper script that invokes BC in the background, something like `#!/bin/sh` <newline> `bcompare "$@" &`. That would give you a new BC window for each comparison. I don't know whether bcompare has a command-line option to open a new tab in an existing window.

Comment: Hit Ctrl-C on the command line?

Comment: Try `git difftool -d`, this will give you a folder view of the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the parameter [--dir-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool#Documentation/git-difftool.txt---dir-diff) this will open up all changes in Bcompare at once.
Additionally you can create an alias in your .gitconfig e.g.

`git config --global alias.bcompare 'difftool --dir-diff'`

then you save some console typing effort :-)